# getting all uploaded files from blueimp file uploader

Tags: jquery, file, file-upload, upload, blueimp

I use the [blueimp file uploader](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload) to upload files to my webspace.
How can I get all files in the list with their status?

I have a separate button which is outside the #fileupload divs and want to get an array or something like that with all files, which were uploaded.

Have I to iterate over the html code and parse the filename and status? I cannot believe that, but I also cannot find a function which returns me this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my question I solved it with iterating over all elements in the list, looking for teh delete button and extracting the filename from the url of the delete button.

```
var files = new Array();
$("#fileupload td.delete button[data-type='DELETE']").each(function() {
    //get the basename of the url: http://abc/def/file.txt --> file.txt
    var name = $(this).attr("data-url").replace(/\\/g,'/').replace( /.*\//, '');
    files.push(name);
});
```

Does someone else has a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

A callback for successful upload is provided:

```
var arrNames = new Array();

//File uploader
$('#fileupload').fileupload().bind('fileuploaddone', 
    function (e, data) {
       //Add names
       arrNames[arrNames.length + 1] = data.result.files[0].name;
    }
);
```

arrNames holds the names of the uploaded files

Answer (score 0):

(...)
   downloadTemplateId: null,
   downloadTemplate: function (o) {
   }
   (...)

You could set `downloadTemplate` function and do here everything that you need with downloaded files. o.files contains response from server.

Answer (score 0):

in file:script.js

add code :

```
getFiles__Name(data.files[0].name);
```

under line :

```
add: function (e, data) {
```

and in your page add :

```
var files=new Array();
function getFiles__Name(name){
    files.push(name);
}
```

where files will contains all file's name.
in my opinion this is not also the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an array of files that had already been uploaded by taking FabriGad Ahmed's answer and tweaking it.

In my view I added the following script:

```
var img_files=[];
function getFiles__Name(name){
img_files.push(name);
}
```

In jquery.fileupload-ui.js i added the following to the **done** function:

```
//get the names of the already uploaded files
if (files){
$.each(files, function( index ) {
getFiles__Name( files[index].name );
});
}
```

This gives me an array of successfully uploaded files. Again, if there is a better way of doing this, I'd love to know.