# jQuery File Upload Previously Uploaded Files Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-file-upload

Environment: .NET 4.51 WebForms

When the page containing jQueryFileUpload loads I want to list the files on the server for the user and allow them to delete them. I have followed other posts:

- [jQuery fileupload - get list of uploaded files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448574/jquery-fileupload-get-list-of-uploaded-files)
- [getting all uploaded files from blueimp file uploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082949/getting-all-uploaded-files-from-blueimp-file-uploader)

and came up with the following code which replaces the start and cancel buttons within the results with a delete button:

```
 <script>             
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            //Initialise plugins
            FormFileUpload.init();

            //Get the images previously uploaded by the user
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:4837/Handlers/JQueryFileUploadHandler.ashx",
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data.files);
                $('#fileupload').fileupload('add', { files: data.files });

                //Remove the Start & Cancel replacing with delete
                $("button").remove(".btn.red.cancel");

                $("table .btn.blue.start").prop('value', 'Delete');
                $("table .btn.blue.start > span").html("Delete");
                $("table .btn.blue.start > i").removeClass("icon-upload");
                $("table .btn.blue.start > i").addClass("icon-trash");
                $("table .btn.blue.start").addClass("red");
                $("table .btn.blue.start.red").removeClass("blue");

                console.log('======');
                $("table .btn.red.start").each(function (index) {
                    var imgFileName = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
                    imgFileName = imgFileName.trim();

                    $(this).attr("data-type", "POST");
                    $(this).attr("data-url", "http://localhost:4837/handlers/JQueryFileUploadHandler.ashx?file=" + imgFileName + "&_method=DELETE");
                    console.log(imgFileName);
                });
                console.log('======');
            });

        });


        //<button data-url="http://localhost:4837/handlers//JQueryFileUploadHandler.ashx?file=V3.png&amp;_method=DELETE" data-type="POST" class="btn red delete">
        //                          <i class="icon-trash"></i>
        //                          <span>Delete</span>
        //                      </button>                                               
        //<input type="checkbox" class="toggle" value="1" name="delete">

    </script>
```

However even though I have what appears to be valid HTML for each entry as:

```
<button class="btn start red" value="Delete" data-type="POST" data-url="http://localhost:4837/handlers/JQueryFileUploadHandler.ashx?file=V3.png&amp;_method=DELETE">
                          <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                          <span>Delete</span>
                      </button>
```

when I click the delete button the submitted URL is only:

```
http://localhost:4837/handlers/JQueryFileUploadHandler.ashx
```

and I am missing the **file** and **_method** request parameters. So my questions are:

a) What do I need to do to fix my solution so that I get the full URL
-- OR --
b) Has anyone got a fully working solution where they get the list of files from the server showing a delete button for each one so that the user can manage previously uploaded files?

Comment: why is this tagged with c# ?

Comment: Because I am doing this using c# webforms so there might be something that .NET is doing to screw me around. My back end handler is an ASHX so .NET is also relevant in that case.